# browsing history in Android emulator

Tags: android, browser, android-emulator, browser-history

I am writing an app that needs access to android browsing history.

I wonder if there is a way to "import" those history to my Emulator?

My Emulator is obviously blank with no history. And it's quite painful to manually create browsing history.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The history for the stock browser appears to be stored in the same database as the bookmarks. [Here's an XDA post on how to get the DB's contents.](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=3223060&postcount=199)

Alternatively, it's possible (depending on android version perhaps) that logging in with the same Google account on both your personal device and emulator would synchronize browsing history.